# Fastest way to construct pyarrow table row by row

Tags: python, pyarrow, apache-arrow

I have a large dictionary that I want to iterate through to build a pyarrow table. The values of the dictionary are tuples of varying types and need to be unpacked and stored in separate columns in the final pyarrow table. I do know the schema ahead of time. The keys also need to be stored as a column. I have a method below to construct the table row by row - is there another method that is faster? For context, I want to parse a large dictionary into a pyarrow table to write out to a parquet file. RAM usage is less of a concern than CPU time. I'd prefer not to drop down to the arrow C++ API.

```
import pyarrow as pa
import random
import string 
import time

large_dict = dict()

for i in range(int(1e6)):
    large_dict[i] = (random.randint(0, 5), random.choice(string.ascii_letters))


schema = pa.schema({
        "key"  : pa.uint32(),
        "col1" : pa.uint8(),
        "col2" : pa.string()
   })

start = time.time()

tables = []
for key, item in large_dict.items():
    val1, val2 = item
    tables.append(
            pa.Table.from_pydict({
                    "key"  : [key],
                    "col1" : [val1],
                    "col2" : [val2]
                }, schema = schema)

            )

table = pa.concat_tables(tables)
end = time.time()
print(end - start) # 22.6 seconds on my machine
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since the schema is known ahead of time, you can make a list for each column and build a dictionary of *column name and column values* pairs.

```
%%timeit -r 10
import pyarrow as pa
import random
import string 
import time

large_dict = dict()

for i in range(int(1e6)):
    large_dict[i] = (random.randint(0, 5), random.choice(string.ascii_letters))


schema = pa.schema({
        "key"  : pa.uint32(),
        "col1" : pa.uint8(),
        "col2" : pa.string()
  })

keys = []
val1 = []
val2 = []
for k, (v1, v2) in large_dict.items():
  keys.append(k)
  val1.append(v1)
  val2.append(v2)

table = pa.Table.from_pydict(
    dict(
        zip(schema.names, (keys, val1, val2))
    ),
    schema=schema
)
```

> 2.92 s ± 236 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 1 loop each)

Comment: Thanks, this is faster. Would you expect any benefit from using pyarrow arrays instead of lists? I know the number of elements ahead of time so could pre-allocate.

Comment: That should prove to be similar performance. `pyarrow` is implicitly converting the native python list to an array https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/c4671b32dfa45d2960d802fbf7099e9eea4a623d/python/pyarrow/table.pxi#L1135

Comment: pyarrow arrays are immutable, so you'll have a hard time appending to them. But you could use `numpy` `ndarray` and that should be faster than python lists.

Comment: If the schema is _not_ known ahead of time, just use`pa.Table.from_pydict()` without a `pa.schema` and it will infer the data types.

Answer (score 3):

I am playing with pyarrow as well. 
For me it seems that in your code *data-preparing stage* (random, etc) is most time consuming part itself. 
So may be first try to convert data into dict of arrays, and then feed them to Arrow Table.

Please look, I make example based on your data and `%%timeit`-ing only Table population stage. But do it with `RecordBatch.from_arrays()` and array of three arrays.

```py
I = iter(pa.RecordBatch.\
         from_arrays(
                      get_data(l0, l1_0, l2, i),
                      schema=schema) for i in range(1000)
        )

T1 = pa.Table.from_batches(I, schema=schema)
```

With static data set 1000 rows batched 1000 times - table is populated with incredible **15 ms** :) Due to caching maybe.
And with 1000 rows modified like col1*integer batched 1000 times - **33.3 ms**, which is also looks nice.

My sample [notebook is here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1nBDJOfuCMR8j-KUSK0bz2Sv-rbZGmIzy)

PS. I was wondering could be numba jit be helpful, but seems it only making timing worse here.