# How can I construct a DataFrame that uses the PyArrow backend directly (i.e., without a pd.read_xx() method)?

Tags: python, pandas, pyarrow

Pandas 2.0 introduces the option to use PyArrow as the backend rather than NumPy. As of version 2.0, using it seems to require either calling one of the `pd.read_xxx()` methods with `type_backend='pyarrow'`, or else constructing a `DataFrame` that's NumPy-backed and then calling `.convert_dtypes` on it.

Is there a more direct way to construct a PyArrow-backed `DataFrame`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your data are known to be all of a specific type (say, `int64[pyarrow]`), this is straightforward:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'col_1': [3, 2, 1, 0], 'col_2': [1, 2, 3, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data,
    dtype='int64[pyarrow]',
    # ...
)
```

---

If your data are known to be all of the same type but the type is not known, then I don't know of a way to use the constructor. I tried `dtype=pd.ArrowDtype`, which does *not* work, and `dtype=pd.ArrowDtype()`, which needs an argument that I think would have to be a specific dtype.

---

One option for possibly-mixed and unknown data types is to make a `pa.Table` (using one of its methods) and then send it to pandas with the `types_mapper` kwarg. For example, using a `dict`:

```
import pyarrow as pa

data = {'col_1': [3, 2, 1, 0], 'col_2': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']}

pa_table = pa.Table.from_pydict(data)
df = pa_table.to_pandas(types_mapper=pd.ArrowDtype)
```

The last line is exactly what `pd.read_parquet` with `dtype_backend='pyarrow'` does under the hood, after reading parquet into a `pa.Table`. I thought it was worth highlighting the approach since it wouldn't have occurred to me otherwise.

The method `pa.Table.from_pydict()` will infer the data types. If the data are of mixed type, but known, and speed is very important, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/57939649 for how to make a predefined schema to pass to the `pa.Table` constructor.

---

The above method loses most of the flexibility of the `DataFrame` constructor (specifying an index, accepting various container types as input, etc.). You might be able to code around this and encapsulate it in a function.

Another workaround, as mentioned in the question, is to just construct a NumPy-backed `DataFrame` and call `.convert_dtypes` on it:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'col_1': [3, 2, 1, 0], 'col_2': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']}
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data,
    index=[4, 5, 6, 7],
    # ...
).convert_dtypes(dtype_backend='pyarrow')
```

Comment: arg to ```convert_dtypes()``` function is ```dtype_backend``` not ```type_backend```

Comment: Using `.convert_dtypes(dtype_backend='pyarrow')` is giving me `NameError: name 'ArrowDtype' is not defined`. I'm not sure why.

Comment: @KGinChicago Which ```pandas``` version?