# pandas.convert_dtype(dtype_backend="pyarrow") raises error

Tags: python, pandas, pyarrow

I'm starting to use pandas with Pyarrow and realized there's no easy way to declare a df directly as with Pyarrow engine, so I ended up in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75939770/how-can-i-construct-a-dataframe-that-uses-the-pyarrow-backend-directly-i-e-wi). The thing is that I'm having the same isssue as one user comment in the accepted answer.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['spam', 'eggs', 'spam', 'eggs'] * 2,
                   'B' : ['alpha', 'beta', 'gamma' , 'foo'] * 2,
                   'C' : [np.random.choice(pd.date_range(datetime.datetime(2013,1,1),datetime.datetime(2013,1,3))) for i in range(8)],
                   'D' : np.random.randn(8),
                   'E' : np.random.random_integers(8)}).convert_dtypes(dtype_backend='pyarrow')
```

This raises `NameError: name 'ArrowDtype' is not defined`

pandas version == 2.1.0

Using vscode with jupyter integrated terminal.

Comment: What is your version of pyarrow? If you have pyarrow < 7.0.0, this might be resolved by upgrading.

Comment: I am seeing the same error.